# What is the workflow to auto connect a remote

Tags: camera, sony, sony-camera-api

The FDR-AX33 has changed the micro USB multi-port and lost LANC control (in favor of power over the multi-port).

The LANC control provided remote power-on and was instantly connected and able to control.

I found, downloaded, and have tested the Camera API - nice work overall.

**With the new API, what is the replacement workflow for the power-on and auto connect.**

I have two scenarios where it's important.

1) a camera is stationed out of reach and accessible only by connected cables. 
2) a camera is inside an underwater housing and accessible only via remote controls.

In both cases the camera will be prepped hours before shooting is ready so it's not feasible to leave the camera on the entire time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sony remote Camera API does not support turning the Camera on automatically. The API actually depends on the camera being on and paired over wifi. You can turn the Camera off using the API, but unfortunately not on. This seems like more of a hardware question though so maybe posting your question in this forum will yield better results:

http://community.sony.com/t5/Cameras-Camcorders/ct-p/digital-still-cameras-camcorders

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for the reply. I'll try the hardware forum, but the question stands as an API question. How, through the API, does one achieve the control scenario starting from off state. Because it's not currently possible, I'd encourage team-api to look holistically at solving the workflow issue.

Comment: If the workflow cannot be achieved programmatically through the Camera Remote API (WiFi) I'd encourage Sony to expose another option to us -- users who are in the practice of using Sony's own LANC to control it's cameras. (USB, LANC workaround, proprietary adapter)  Thanks again for the reply. Hope you can eventually help otherwise I just purchased a brick to go in an underwater housing.

Comment: Sorry for not being able to be of more help on this. I will however be sure that the API team is aware of your issue and your suggestion.

Comment: Well, at least it's a pretty brick. Maybe I can find another use for it. If you don't mind, please also contact marketing to include a note about the exclusion of LANC control in the marketing material. Quietly changing functionality of the multiport is IMHO not fair play.  Thanks for your time.